# How to specify RTL specific drawables

Tags: android, right-to-left

I have few images that looks different on right-to-left.
Is it possible to create rtl specific drawable directory or some rtl post-fix for file names to auto-load relevant images?
Looks like ldrtl post-fix, added from 17 lvl, is good only for layouts directory.

Comment: res/layout-ldrtl/ (Right to Left)

Comment: I am taking about Drawables(images), not layouts.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's pretty late to answer this question, but I want to share a method that I just found out. I will first recap what is mentioned by the others.

---

Let's start with a **specification**.

We need to build something like:

`login --> take picture --> win prize`

In RTL, it will become:

`ezirp niw <-- erutcip ekat <-- nigol`

So the big question is how we flip the drawable arrow, let's call it `arrow_right.png`:

 `-->`

and in RTL you want it to be like this:

 `<--`

---

For **Android >=19**

As others mentioned, we can use the `autoMirrored=true` flag. [(available from API19)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setAutoMirrored(boolean))

The usage:

```
<ImageView ...
    src="@drawable/arrow_right"
    autoMirrored="true" />
```

The assets:

```
   ├── drawable-xxxhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-xxhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-xhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-hdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-mdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
```

Note that:

- `arrow_right.png` inside `drawable-*` contain `-->`

Remarks:
The only downside is that it's not backward compatible.

---

**For Android <19, Option 1**

Like others have pointed out, you can use the `ldrtl` option. [(doc: Providing Resources)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

The usage:

```
<ImageView ...
    src="@drawable/arrow_right" />
```

The assets:

```
   ├── drawable-xxxhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-xxhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-xhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-hdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-mdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-ldrtl-hdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-ldrtl-mdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
```

Note that:

- `arrow_right.png` inside `drawable-*` contain `-->`
- `arrow_right.png` inside `drawable-ldrtl-*` contain `<--`.

Remarks: 
There is nothing wrong with this method, except you need to prepare like 10x assets files. So it leads me to find out the next option.

---

**For Android <19, Option 2**

This option will be using the `rotationY="180"` attributes. [(available from API11)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotationY(float))

If you set `rotationY="180"` to `ImageView`, `-->` will turn into `<--`.

So we can do something like the following.

The usage:

```
<ImageView ...
    src="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:rotationY="@integer/angle_rtl_180" />
```

The assets:

```
  drawable
   ├── drawable-xxxhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-xxhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-xhdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-hdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── drawable-mdpi
        └── arrow_right.png
   ├── values
        └── integers.xml
   ├── values-ldrtl
        └── integers.xml
```

Note:

- `arrow_right.png` contains `-->`
- `values/integers` contains
  `<integer name="angle_rtl_180">0</integer>`
- `values-ldrtl/integers` contains
  `<integer name="angle_rtl_180">180</integer>`

Remarks: You only need 1 set of assets, and this solution can be used from API 11, and the usage is simple enough by simply adding `android:rotationY="@integer/angle_rtl_180"`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Very well explained thanks a lot. it worked for me like charm :)

Comment: Thanks for explain. 
if not working than please set rotation as programmatically.

Comment: "For Android <19, Option 1" is the most correct answer

Comment: How can I apply the solution For Android >=19 to be in drawable itself to be used in none image views like Button icon or used directly in style drawable?

Comment: I tried the solution For Android >=19 for ImageView but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 48):

For 17+ (4.2.x+) you can use layout direction (**ld**) resources qualifier, for right to left (RTL) you can use **ldrtl** and for left to right (LTR) you can use **ldltr**, e.g. you can use

`res/
  drawable // Default
  drawable-ldltr // LTR
  drawable-ldrtl // RTL`

Also as any other qualifier you can combine it with many others e.g. `drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi`, please note how *ldrtl* comes before *xhdpi* otherwise aapt will complain.

And as @Dennis mentioned from 19+ (4.4+) it gets easier as you can use [autoMirrored](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#autoMirrored)

Comment: What's drawable-fa, @Mr.Hyde? Couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: @lidkxx Nothing. It was my mistake. `fa` is for Persian language and it's an RTL language. At that time, I meant how should I add these `ldltr` & `ldrtl` to a folder which has this `drawable-fa` name. But now I got it; Just need to create `drawable-ldrtl` for layouts on the Persian language.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I find this more useful because i want compeletly different drawable for RTL.

Answer (score 13):

There's an option to auto-mirror the drawable. Check [autoMirrored](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#autoMirrored) attribute.

Comment: I need honeycomb support, auto-mirror is supported only starting from 19 lvl.