# textView for rtl and ltr (API 14)

Tags: android, layout, right-to-left, direction

I have a `TextView` with `android:paddingRight` and I want to support API 14

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_name"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size_plus_margin"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lines="1"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size_plus_margin"/>
```

I want to create two layouts (`RTL` and `LTR`).

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593628/how-to-specify-rtl-specific-drawables) about `LTR` and `RTL` drawables

but how would I do the `merge` and folders for layouts xml?

Comment: Could you clarify what is your question? Do you want to have padding on the same side for both directions or do you want to have it changed? There is rarely need for separate layouts for both directions

Comment: yes, i have added the code. sorry

Comment: according to the android documentation if you want RTL support below API 17 you have to add android:paddingRight also with the android:paddingEnd and parallelly I don't think so you have to create two layouts for this. Please add images with regards to your problem for better understanding.

Comment: but what happens for API 14 and rtl when it ignores paddingEnd? then i need to align to paddingLeft ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have padding on the right regardless of the direction of the layout you should use `paddingRight` but if you want to have padding on the right for ltr layout but on the left fot rtl layout you should use `paddingEnd`.

The same applies for margins and constraints in `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: yes, but I want to support API level 14. TextView attribute

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) if you're targeting API below 17 you should use both attributes `start` and `left` with `end` and `right`

Comment: but for api14 android ignores "end" and i need to choose left(rtl) and right(ltr)

Comment: Yes. My suggestion is to target api 17+ since only 1.7% of all Android devices are on below that. It's not worth the work you would need to put into it.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you should be worried about that. Even the android system itself doesn't support RTL layout before api 17. The only way you could implement that is make separate layout for each configuration and then based on locale serve that layout. Something like BaseActivity and BaseFragment having two abstract methods like `provideLayout` and `provideRtlLayout`. And they would decide which one to inflate.